# How do I stop FileVault's decryption?

Tags: macos, filevault

I accidentally turned off FileVault on my MacBook when trying to allow downloaded Canon driver software to be opened. FileVault is currently decrypting and I want to stop it as soon as possible. How do I stop FileVault decryption?

Answer (score 8):

You have to let it finish FileVault decryption entirely before you can turn it back on. This can take hours or sometimes days, so you'll have to be patient. Encryption also takes nearly as long. There's nothing to do but wait for it to complete.

If you have a MacBook, be sure to keep it plugged in, as FileVault wont decrypt or encrypt while on battery power.

You should still be able to use your computer while it decrypts/encrypts.

Comment: Sorry for +1, but the OS knows what it's doing. Let it finish and turn it back on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait but you can still use your mac while you wait.